# Percentage displayed in a chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

[image]

I'm trying to put this in a line graph to show the percentage of the OnDuration over a monthly period

I have put the expression below in the 'values' part of the chart and formatted the y-axis to percent but the output is not coming out as I would expect. My inability at maths is probably letting me down here!

```
=Sum(Fields!OnDuration.Value / Fields!TotalSecondsInMonth.value)
```

The 'PercentageON' field is just something i've added in Excel. This would be the correct percentage for an individual employee in one month. On my graph I would like to show the percentage for the whole department. There would

Comment: Is the sample data you provided exactly what comes back from your dataset query or is this aggregated from your dataset query? If it's aggregated, please show the actual data returned, or at least a small sample of it.

Comment: Also, what results are you getting vs what you expect? I assume the top row you would expect 0.529 (52.9%) ?

Comment: @Alan Schofield I've made some edits, hope this helps, thanks

Comment: It's still not clear what you want on the chart? Is it a line per department and months on the x-axis? If so then you probably want to change the expression to `=Sum(Fields!OnDuration.Value) / SUM(Fields!TotalSecondsInMonth.value)`. If not then just show the data you have in your dataset (nothing more) and what you expect the results to look like, or it's just more guess work